# Number of windows opened is displayed wrongly in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the below code and I was expecting that in console I should get
Total windows opened: 1
But the result was Total windows opened: 2
Please let me know why its showing Total windows opened: 2 instead of 1

> **Firefox Version:** 48.0.2 **OS:** Windows 10 **Selenium Webdriver Version:**
>   3.0.0

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TravelOPod {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      Set<String> windowIDs = driver.getWindowHandles();
      System.out.println("Total windows opened: "+windowIDs.size());
      Iterator<String> it = windowIDs.iterator();
      System.out.println(it.next());
      System.out.println(it.next());
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is only one window opened while it returns two??

Answer (score 0):

I think, the first tab is your default tab and the other tab opening may be caused by one of your extensions.

You can check for nonessential or unrecognized extensions on the Add-ons page.

I hope, disabling your unexpected extensions may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> driver.getWindowHandles();

This returns the Set of Strings, that is nothing but hashcode value of window object. So, in your case you have two window objects, first one is by default and the second one is for the new tab opened

I guess, you are confusing yourself because of the statement you are printing,

> System.out.println("Total windows opened: "+windowIDs.size());

It is not printing the size of "opened" windows, instead the available windows

if you want to get hold of only one window, then use 
driver.getWindowHandle(); // this returns the current driver object in String